# iScroll stop scrolling left/right (horizontal), not working out for me am I doing it wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

```
function iScrollLoaded()
{
//(function($){
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper',
    {
        hideScrollbar:true,
        hScroll:false,
        bounce:true,
        lockDirection:true,
    });
//})(jQuery)
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', iScrollLoaded, false);
```

As I understand if from the iScroll page this should stop the screen from being able to be dragged left/right but.. seems it holds no effect, is there anyway to keep the scroll wrapper from dragging left/right or am I doing it wrong here?

basic example of the HTML in use..

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header" class="clearfix">
        <div class="header_logo">
            <a href="domain.com/" title="domains">
                <img src="/logo_600.png" style="border:none;" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <!-- sub_nav -->
    <!-- /sub_nav -->
    <div id="wrapper" class="no_snav">
        <div id="scroller" class="overthrow">   
        <div>This profile is currently unavailable or does not exist.</div>
        <div id="geolocation_latlng" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
        </div><!-- /scroller -->
    </div><!-- /wrapper -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: can you post your html code also?

Comment: added some html to the post for sake of example

Comment: try removing the `,` in `lockDirection:true,` and rerun the code.

Comment: change the **hScroll** to **true**; **hScroll:true** . You are disabling the horizontalScroll here

Answer (score 1):

This is your code block. Here you specify `hScroll:false`. It means disable the horizontal scroll. Make it `hScroll:true` and check it.

**Your code**

```
function iScrollLoaded()
{
//(function($){
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper',
    {
        hideScrollbar:true,
        hScroll:false, /* THIS SHOULD BE TRUE FOR HORIZONTAL SCROLLING */
        bounce:true,
        lockDirection:true,
    });
//})(jQuery)
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', iScrollLoaded, false);
```